# How to check if part of a string equals another string in android

Tags: java

How do I check if part if one string is equal to another?
For example if I have one string with the value of "hello" and a string with the value of "he", how can I compare them to check that "hello" contains "he".

If that was not explained very well tell me and I will try to clear it up

Comment: `String1.contains(String2);` if you're trying to find out if `String2` is a substring of `String1`.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Do you mean ANY part of the string contained in the other?

Comment: Yes, so "llo" could also be true

Comment: Check out my answer too, might find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`"Hello".toLowerCase().contains("He".toLowercase());` same like java by using String class [contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method on `String`:

```
String str = "Hello";

if (str.toLowerCase().contains("he"))
    // ...
```

There is also a [`startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method on `String`:

```
if (str.toLowerCase().startsWith("he"))
    // ...
```

If both strings are variables with unknown contents, and case isn't important, then:

```
str.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase()))
str.toLowerCase().startsWith(str2.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try String.contains(). Docs can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 3):

If you are unsure of the case of the strings, convert both to lower case:

```
if("Hello".toLowerCase().indexOf("he".toLowerCase()) >= 0)
```

Comment: I think this is perfect if you want non-case sensitive check.

Answer (score 1):

```
string string1 = "yellow";
string string2 = "Hello";
boolean contains = false;

int length = string1.length();

for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (int j=i+1; j < length; j++)
    {
        // Don't go beyond last letter for second part of substring
        if (j < length - 1)
        {
            string temp = string1.substring(i, j);
            contains == string2.contains(temp);
        }
    }
}
```